# Red Black Tree Rule Enforcement in Java

Tags: java, tree, red-black-tree

I'm trying to implement a Red-Black Tree in Java. To do this, I'm allowing each insert to happen as if it were a BST and then post-insert I pre-order traverse the tree and check each Node (which I call a Word as I'm using it for a dictionary application) that the Red-Black Rules are satisfied. So far it looks like this

```
private void checkRedBlackRules(Word w)
    {

        //Checking for Red-Red sequence
        Word leftChild = w.getLeft(); 
        Word rightChild = w.getRight();
        Word leftleftGC, leftrightGC, rightleftGC, rightrightGC;
        if(leftChild != null)
        {
            leftleftGC = leftChild.getLeft();
            leftrightGC = leftChild.getRight();
        }
        else
        {
            leftleftGC = null;
            leftrightGC = null;
        }
        if(rightChild != null)
        {
            rightleftGC = rightChild.getLeft();
            rightrightGC = rightChild.getRight();
        }
        else
        {
            rightleftGC = null;
            rightrightGC = null;
        }
        try
        {
            if(leftChild.isRed() && leftleftGC.isRed())
            {
                rotateRight(w, leftChild, leftleftGC);
            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e) {}
        try
        {
            if(leftChild.isRed() && leftrightGC.isRed())
            {

            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e) {}
        try
        {
            if(rightChild.isRed() && rightleftGC.isRed())
            {

            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e) {}
        try
        {
            if(rightChild.isRed() && rightrightGC.isRed())
            {
                rotateLeft(w, leftChild, leftrightGC);
            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e) {}
        if(w.getLeft() != null)
            checkRedBlackRules(w.getLeft());
        if(w.getRight() != null)
            checkRedBlackRules(w.getRight());
    }

    private void rotateLeft(Word parent, Word child, Word grandChild)
    {
        child = parent;
        child.setLeft(parent);
        child.setRight(grandChild);
    }
    private void rotateRight(Word parent, Word child, Word grandChild)
    {
        child = parent;
        child.setLeft(grandChild);
        child.setRight(parent);
    }
```

However, when I try to add more than two elements to the tree it gets stuck in an endless loop until a StackOverflow error occurs.

Comment: Why are you indiscriminately catching and ignoring `NullPointerException`s? That's _definitely_ not the right thing to do.

Comment: The rotate functions look odd... `child = parent; child.setLeft(parent);` is like saying `parent.setLeft(parent);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going through all of the logic in detail, the rotate functions look incorrect to me:

```
private void rotateLeft(Word parent, Word child, Word grandChild)
{
    child = parent;
    child.setLeft(parent);
    child.setRight(grandChild);
}
```

The child parameter is not used, and is instead immediately set to the parent. This means that when you call child.setLeft(parent), you're setting the original parent's left child to itself, which I believe is what is causing an infinite loop (and therefore the stack overflow).